# c++ webservice having problems with Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: iis

About Problem:- We have a webservice written in c++.And we use cgi scripts in HTML pages to run our own exe which will output HTML. With IE i am not seeing any problem. But With Mozilla FireFox 3.0 there is error showing up as

" You have chosen to open gefebt.exe  which is a : Application from http:\3.212.219.180\test  Would you like to save this file"

Also i did some investigation :- i have created a virtual directory using IIS where when i click hyperlink i have made gefebt.exe to execute. With IIS there is no problem untill Execute Permissions is set to "Scripts and Executables" . If i select scripts i could see the same message in IE and mozilla plugin.

At the same time i not seeing any difference with the code of Webservice.
The way we are reffering the executable in HTML is  href=gefebt.exe?xyz.bcl>Invoke xyz.bcl - I have also tries with IFrames and frames .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending wrong http headers.
Try adding `Content-type: text/html`

Comment: Thanks for looking into.

Yup i have added code so that webserver send Content-type: text/html in HTTP headers.

Now i am not seeing any thing on the HTML.

Comment: i am not seeing the above message though, but i am not seeing any thing

Comment: Do i need to add any other HTTP headers. Sorry i am new to these HTTP protocol.

Comment: try reading this: http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/ it really helped me when i was working with http. And also try to have a look at the real data you're sending to the client.